# using output of Bag Of words to other dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I'm trying to do on the dataset (that contains sentences) BagOfwords algorithm and the output of the bag of words algorithm (after it cleaned all the words that aren't important) will get into the second dataset (that contains divided data i will put pictures in the bottom) but my problem is how to attach the output of the first dataset to be good to get into the second dataset training. I thought about doing a dictionary to convert and divide the sentences to be good to the second dataset values but its very hard I hope you have a better idea.

sample from the first dataset that ive do on him BagOf words
"I have been experiencing a skin rash on my arms, legs, and torso for the past few weeks. It is red, itchy, and covered in dry, scaly patches."

picure from the second dataset that im trying to connect the first dataset to the neaural networks of the second dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkojK.png)